# What does brackets (eg. SomeType[]) mean in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

What does `HTMLElement[]` mean in TypeScript (as compared to plain `HTMLElement` without the brackets?)

Comment: It indicates a list of that type. ie, `const x : String = "X"; const y: String[] = ["Y"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`HTMLElement[]` is the type for an array of HTMLElements. For example, the following would be typed as such:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll<HTMLElement>('div')]
```

Another way of writing the type of an array of elements is with angle brackets, eg:

```
Array<HTMLElement>
```

which is equivalent to `HTMLElement[]`.

`HTMLElement`, in contrast, is just be a single element, eg

```
document.querySelector<HTMLElement>('div')!;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
declare type element: HTMLElement; // an html element

declare type elements: HTMLElement[]; // an array of html elements
```

When you declare a specific type for an array, you can only push given type to the array.

If we declare `HTMLInputElement[]` type for an array. We cant push a textarea item to the this array. Only specified type allowed

Answer (score 2):

That's one of the ways to write TypeScript arrays. One can either specify the type followed by square brackets (`const list: number[] = [1, 2, 3];`) or simply use the generic array type (`const list: Array<number> = [1, 2, 3];`).

So, `HTMLElement[]` is an array of type HTMLElements.